# ОК триггер по завершению бэкапа

Tags: zabbix, rsnapshot

Создал триггер для мониторинга лога `rsnapshot`, который отсылает оповещение о законченном копировании.

Как правильно оформить выражение, что бы "проблема" автоматический завершалась (как пример - оповещение о перезагрузке или измененной версии)

Текущая версия триггера:

```
{Log aggregator:log[/var/log/rsnapshot.log].str(daily: completed,#20)}=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас Zabbix версии 3.2 и старше, используйте генерацию ОК событий в настройках триггера.
Выражение восстановления:

```
{Log aggregator:log[/var/log/rsnapshot.log].str(daily:completed,#20)}=0
```

Это означает, что триггер переходит в состояние OK, если строка completed не обнаружена.